# Query performance in minimongo

Tags: javascript, meteor

I built a responsive forum demo which rendered a topic list on the mobile device. It was unresponsive when the collection was updated. I think the reason is the slowly query.

My test html:

```
<template name="index">
  <h1 id="myTime"></h1>
  {{#each foo}}
  <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  {{/each}}
  <input id="t" type="text"></input>
  <button id="s">submit</button>
</template>
```

and js:

```
Template.index.foo = function () {
  return Foo.find({}).fetch();
};

Template.index.events({
  "click #s": function () {
    Foo.insert({name: $("#t").val()});
  }
});

Meteor.startup(function () {
  Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    $("#myTime").text((new Date()).getTime());
  }, 1);
});
```

when the number of documents is very small, the code works very fast. when the number of documents is larger than 300 , rendering will stop about 3s

Is it possible to improve it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing DOM insertions at every iteration of the loop? It's easier to create a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DocumentFragment), append everything to that, and then append the fragment in the DOM at the end of the loop.
The logic stays almost the same, but the browser has to repaint the page only once at the end, as opposed to every iteration.

Comment: thanks! I have no DOM operation code. All DOM operation is handled by template. And the delay is before `Template.index.rendered`(I added a `alert` in the rendered function and it alerted after the delay)